# $1 / (2 \pi)$ factor in Fourier transform

Tags: integration, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, dirac-delta

I have been unable to see why the $1 / (2 \pi)$ appears in Fourier transform. Would you please justify it to me?

**Problem:**
Let 
$$
f(x) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} k \,  e^{ikx} \tilde{f}(k) \, .
$$
Why does it hold that
$$
\tilde{f}(k) = \frac{1}{2 \pi} \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \mathrm{d} x \,  e^{-ikx} \tilde{f}(k) \, ?
$$
Especially, where does the $1 / (2 \pi)$ come from?

I think I understand how the thing should behave for functions on $x \in [0,P]$. Provided that
$$
f(x) = \sum_k \tilde{f}_k e^{ikx} \,
$$
for $k \in \{ \frac{2 \pi n}{P} \, \mathrm{for} \, n \in Z \}$, then
$$
\int_0^P \mathrm{d} x \, e^{-ikx} f(x) = \sum_q \tilde{f}_q \int_0^P \mathrm{d} x \, e^{ix(k-q)} \, . 
$$
$$
\int_0^P \mathrm{d} x \, e^{ix(k-q)} = \frac{1}{i (k-q)}{e^{iP(k-q)} - 1} = P \delta_{kq} \, ,
$$
Therefore
$$
\int_0^P \mathrm{d} x \, e^{-ikx} f(x) = P \tilde{f}_k \, .
$$
To have everything properly normalized, I have
$$
\tilde{f}_k = \frac{1}{P} \int_0^P \mathrm{d} x \, e^{-ikx} f(x) \, .
$$

Moving to $x \in R$, the $2 \pi$ seems to play the same role as $P$, but I do not see why.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: do you know the identity $\int_{\mathbb{R}}e^{ikx}dk=2\pi\delta(x)}$?

Comment: I do. But I do not want to use it in the proof as I can't prove it either. Would you be able to prove it instead of my question without using the defn at the beginning of it?

Comment: which representations of the delta function could u use?

Comment: It's an absolute miracle that  your second formula holds, and you complain about a factor $2\pi\>$?

Comment: Be it a miracle from the pure perspective or not, it is used a lot in physics. That's why I am asking, actually. I stumbled upon a lot of different deltas in quantum field theory and realized that I don't really know where the $2 \pi$ come from.

Comment: Because $\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\sin x}{x}dx = \frac{\pi}{2}$.